# Bootstrap 5 not allowing me to center elements properly

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm new to bootstrap, trying some things out.

I came across an issue where this centers properly:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border p-3">Column</div>
    <div class="col border p-3">Column</div>
    <div class="col border p-3">Column</div>
  </div>enter code here
```

But putting any kind of element within the columns like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border"><p>Column</p></div>
    <div class="col border"><p>Column</p></div>
    <div class="col border"><p>Column</p></div>
  </div>
```

It adds this extra space on the bottom of the column or row and doesn't allow me to properly align-items-center it.

Codepen example:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border"><p class='bg-primary text-white'>Column</p></div>
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border"><p class='bg-primary text-white'>Column</p></div>
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border"><p class='bg-primary text-white'>Column</p></div>
</div>
```

It will align horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: My first question would be, why do you need the d-flex justify-content-center and align-items-center on the cols? you can put align-items-center on the row. remove the margin-bottom of the p elements

Comment: Sorry @GertB. that was my bad on the where I put the "d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center." Typo when I made the snippet. I also didn't know that bootstrap pre-modified the elements.. I just thought classes modified them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap defines this CSS rule for `p` elements :

```
p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

You can either override it or use a different element.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea the p element was pre-styled; just that classes styled the elements.

Comment: A tip for next time: In the element inspector you can see what styles are set in what file.